# What is the Boeing 727 AC Generator Panel Part Number?

Tags: flight-instruments

Does anyone know the part number for the Boeing 727 AC Generator Drive panel?  I have searched the Internet and have not found the part number.

[image]
<sup>([Source](http://www.2040-parts.com/boeing-727-ac-generator-drive-panel-used-aircraft-part-i638595/))</sup>

Comment: That is an oddly specific question. Not that there's anything wrong with it, just... unusual... Mind if I ask why?

Comment: 69.17528.5? ([source](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/BOEING-727-AC-GENERATOR-DRIVE-PANEL-USED-AIRCRAFT-PART-/161044502088), don't know if it's reliable). I added a photo to your post. Hope you don't mind, you can edit an roll back if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

The part number is 69-17528-XX, where XX (the *dash number*) varies based on customer preferences and when the aircraft was produced. Without knowing specifically about the particular airplane the module came from, there is no way to know the part's dash number without physically examining it. See the image below from a search of [Icon Aerospace](http://www.iconaerospace.com/capabilities/capability-search/)'s capability list. Directly searching the capabilities lists of FAA/EASA-licensed repair stations usually yields more reliable results than searching parts "aggregator" or "locator" sites. For example, [this list](http://www.aecnrc.com/PDF/727Capabilites.pdf) links the part number specifically to a 727.

[image: Icon Aerospace capability search]